# By how much does space-time curvature modify the density of an object?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, spacetime, density

Let's imagine a transparent object with a density $\rho_0$ [$kg/m^3$] (A sphere of glass as example). Now I send through this object a long flat impulse of electromagnetic plane wave with frequency $\nu$ and intensity $I$ [$W/m^2$] such that it adds an energy density E [$J/m^3$] into the object during the duration of the pulse. While the pulse is passing through the object, I measure its density $\rho_1$. Has it changed with respect to $\rho_0$ and if yes, by what order of magnitude ?

Comment: density will change, but not so much because of gravity, but because of other physical effects caused by the interaction of electromagnetic waves with glass.

Comment: There are some things you need to understand, including some misconceptions inherent in the way you state the question. (1) This has nothing to do with general relativity or spacetime curvature. The leading-order relativistic effect is a special-relativistic effect. (2) Mass isn't additive in SR, energy and momentum are. (3) The stress-energy of an EM plane wave is not just an energy density component, it's also a non-isotropic pressure.

Comment: if you are thinking of the effects of general relativity see how small they are in my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/446928/do-vibrations-increase-an-objects-mass-or-weight/447084#447084

Comment: Alex: yes you're right, so I should precise that in this question I want to ignore the effect of electrostriction as well as the radiation pressure appearing at the boundaries. Ben: (1) My reason for sending light is to increase the energy at  this portion of space and thus increase the space-time curvature. Doesn't it work this way?. (2) and (3) I don't really understand the relation with my question.